# Does a member have to be initialized to take its address?

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, language-lawyer

Can I initialize a pointer to a data member before initializing the member? In other words, is this valid C++?

```
#include <string>

class Klass {
public:
    Klass()
        : ptr_str{&str}
        , str{}
    {}
private:
    std::string *ptr_str;
    std::string str;
};
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33503206/10147399) question is similar to mine, but the order is correct there, and the answer says

> I'd advise against coding like this in case someone changes the order of the members in your class.

Which seems to mean reversing the order would be illegal but I couldn't be sure.

Comment: Just curious why do you need it?

Comment: @vahancho I am adding a private vector to the end of a class (so it is physically separate from the interface) but this vector takes pointers to some public members. I would like to know if I have to move it up or if this is fine.

Comment: just make sure you do not try to access the member before its actually there

Comment: @Ayxan Language-lawyer questions might bring into this site interesting discussions. I would therefore suggest to wait a little longer with such a quick acceptance of the first answer. Though it may be correct, other opinions might be valuable as well.

Comment: @DanielLangr nice suggestion.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Does a member have to be initialized to take its address?

No.

> Can I initialize a pointer to a data member before initializing the member? In other words, is this valid C++?

Yes. Yes.

There is no restriction that operand of unary & need to be initialised. There is an example in the standard in specification of unary & operator:

> ```
> int a;
> int* p1 = &a;
> ```

Here, the value of `a` is indeterminate and it is OK to point to it.

What that example doesn't demonstrate is pointing to an object before its lifetime has begun, which is what happens in your example. *Using* a pointer to an object before and after its lifetime is explicitly allowed if the storage is occupied. Standard draft says:

> [basic.life] Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that represents the address of the storage location where the object will be or was located may be used but only in limited ways ...

The rule goes on to list how the usage is restricted. You can get by with common sense. In short, you can treat it as you could treat a `void*`, except violating these restrictions is UB rather than ill-formed. Similar rule exists for references.

There are also restrictions on computing the address of non-static members specifically. Standard draft says:

> [class.cdtor] ... To form a pointer to (or access the value of) a direct non-static member of an object `obj`, the construction of `obj` shall have started and its destruction shall not have completed, otherwise the computation of the pointer value (or accessing the member value) results in undefined behavior.

In the constructor of `Klass`, the construction of `Klass` has started and destruction hasn't completed, so the above rule is satisfied.

---

P.S. Your class is copyable, but the copy will have a pointer to the member of another instance. Consider whether that makes sense for your class. If not, you will need to implement custom copy and move constructors and assignment operators. A self-reference like this is a rare case where you may need custom definitions for those, but not a custom destructor, so it is an exception to the rule of five (or three).

P.P.S If your intention is to point to one of the members, and no object other than a member, then you might want to use a pointer to member instead of pointer to object.

Comment: It would be nice to quote relevant parts of the Standard. These might be relevant: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#6.sentence-1 and http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#3.sentence-2.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for looking those up.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between your example and the OP's example. In your example, the lifetime of the variable `a` has begun, but it was not initialized. In the OP's example, the address of a member is taken before its lifetime. Given that your quotations of the standard already adequately address the OP's question, I think the example should be deleted.

Comment: @Brian OP's specifically asks about initialization. The quoted rule doesn't explicitly address initialization (no rule addresses it; there simply isn't a rule related to initialization to my knowledge). Sure, lack of lifetime implies lack of initialization, but I prefer to be explicit. In my opinion, the example demonstrating lack of initialization is useful even if it is technically made redundant by the lifetime rule.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61780925/why-cant-i-use-uniform-initialization-when-i-want-to-override-a-value/61781021#comment109280173_61781021) comment says `int a;` *is* initialized. Default-initialized (with an indeterminate value).

Comment: @Ayxan Initialised with indeterminate value and uninitialised are two ways to say the same thing. "Default initialisation" is a formal name for the syntax. "Uninitialised" is a description of the behaviour that default initialisation has in this case.