# Why can't I use uniform initialization when I want to override a value?

Tags: c++

```
bool a{ false };
```

Now I created a boolean variable, but if I want to do this:

```
a { false };
```

```
a = false;
```

The first method doesn't work, what's the reason?

Comment: Because you're not *initializing* `a` in that expression. And in the last expression, you're assigning.

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613341/what-do-the-following-phrases-mean-in-c-zero-default-and-value-initializat

Comment: Because when you "override" it, you are not initializing it anymore! You can only initialize it once.

Answer (score 2):

You can only do uniform initialization (or any form of initialization) when an object is created. After an object is initialized, you can only modify it:

```
bool a{false}; // brace initialization
bool b = false; // copy initialization

// a and b are created now, and can't be initialized again

a {false}; // not valid syntax
b = false; // assignment, NOT initialization
```

Comment: *"You can only do uniform initialization (or any form of initialization) when you create an object."* I don't think that's correct. `int a; /* <-uninitialized */ a = 0 /* <-now it's initialized*/`.

Comment: @Ayxan - Nope, it's still assigned. You example has it default-initialized (with an indeterminate value).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Then why we call `int a;` uninitialized?

Comment: Isn't the `int` initialized anyway? It's only that the *value* is indeterminate. I think calling it *uninitialized* is technically incorrect.

Comment: @Ayxan - We don't. Not when talking pedantically. Colloquially one may say it's uninitialized. But in the C++ model, no object comes into existence uninitialized (even if said initialization is a no-op).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I thought default initialization was like zero initialization. Thank you for correcting. Where can I learn more about the C++ object model?

Comment: @Ayxan - I think cppreference has good articles about the various initialization types in C++.  You can also start at http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#1 - but delving into [dcl.init] is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica one more question. If I do `malloc(100)` am I given a pointer to uninitialized memory or default initialized memory? I don't think a block of memory is an object, but yeah.

Comment: [The aforementioned cppreference docs on initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: @Ayxan - That was actually the $50,000 question for a long time. It was recently resolved with the adoption of https://wg21.link/p0593

Comment: [More cppreference docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object) on what is and isn't an object.